# Need results for specific date range against previous year - bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

Trying to find a way to compare my results to previous year in bigquery, I have checked through SO but no luck. Any ideas?

```
SELECT store_name,
sum(case when DATE(transaction_date) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND CURRENT_DATE() then (sales) else 0 end) as 30_day_sales,
sum(case when DATE(transaction_date) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND CURRENT_DATE() then orders else 0 end) as 24_hours_orders,
sum(case when DATE(transaction_date) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) AND CURRENT_DATE() then orders else 0 end) as 3_days_orders,
sum(case when DATE(transaction_date) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURRENT_DATE() then orders else 0 end) as 7_days_orders
from pbca
WHERE date(transaction_date)>="2018-01-01"
group by store_name
ORDER BY 30_day_sales
```

I would like to find a way to compare year on year and potentially change the transaction_date>="2018-01-01" to current year so I don't need to change this every new year.

Expected outcomes, 
`Store_name|30_day_sales|24_hours_orders|3_days_orders|7_days_orders|30_day_sales_lastyear|24_hours_orders_lastyear|3_days_orders_lastyear|7_days_orders_lastyear`

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like the below SQL where you can have a table where you can store the latest date and use a correlated query to fetch the latest date from that other table and compare it with your main table.

```
WITH temp_data AS (
  SELECT  timestamp('2019-10-12') AS transaction_date, 'Electronic' as store_name , 100 as sales, 50 as orders UNION ALL
  SELECT  timestamp('2019-10-05') AS transaction_date, 'Sports' as store_name, 101 as sales, 51 as orders  UNION ALL
  SELECT  timestamp('2019-10-03') AS transaction_date, 'Media' as store_name, 102 as sales, 52 as orders  
)
SELECT store_name,
sum(case when DATE(transaction_date) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND CURRENT_DATE() then (sales) else 0 end) AS day_sales_30 ,
sum(case when DATE(transaction_date) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND CURRENT_DATE() then orders else 0 end) AS hours_orders_24,
sum(case when DATE(transaction_date) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) AND CURRENT_DATE() then orders else 0 end) AS days_orders_3,
sum(case when DATE(transaction_date) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURRENT_DATE() then orders else 0 end) AS days_orders_7
from temp_data
WHERE DATE(transaction_date) >= (SELECT DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE() , INTERVAL 180 DAY ))
GROUP BY store_name
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. Could you explain how this would give me a difference between current year results to previous? I need the timestamp to be static as this would be a scheduled query.

Comment: Can you give an example of year over year comparison?

Comment: For my example, how would I get current date, subtract 1 year for this with interval of 30 days for that year and give me results?